# Cassandra delta/relative querying

Tags: select, cassandra, cql, database-partitioning, delta

I have to orchestrate a batch which copy the delta of a table each day. This table is only written, never updated. I use java with jdbc and I wonder if there is a metadata or something on the table which can be queried to get all the rows added after a certains date.

---

Why a metadata ?
Because with my table looking like :

```
CREATE TABLE aTable (
  aTable_id timeuuid,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY ((aTable_id))
) WITH
...
```

I can't put the timeuuid key in the where clause like :

```
SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE aTable_id > minTimeuuid(?)
```

And the token function, even if the `aTable_id` is correctly ordered give me wrong results :

```
SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE token(aTable_id) > token(minTimeuuid(?))
```

In a nutshell, my question is : how to get aTables newer than a certain date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I end up with a solution, found in a meetup introducing cassandra 3.0.

Remember that the schema was set for another request and the keys were not set for a delta request.

The aim for me was to query just the updated row from the previous batch and here the way I did :

- Create a index table, partitioned on date hour (the minutes, seconds and millis are truncated). This table is fed by a gobal index from the main table.
- In java, query the index by hour (`loop on a calendar`) and select the main table with a `IN` query.
- Job done !

Comment: So queries with `IN` is the solution , 
Does that mean we are not supposed to use ranges in partition keys at all?

Comment: Nope, if you use it in real time for example and if it's the main purpose of the table, you have to add date_hour to your partition keys. But if you do analytics stuff, like a daily delta, you can use an index table. Don't forget that Cassandra isn't an RDMBS and you have to think query to build the table structure. To finish, I'd say that with the new Cassandra you can make it more sexy with direct index, but I'm done with the project and alas I don't remember very well cassandra stuff.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. I think you're not supposed to do so because if it was allowed, you would have to scan the entire database. But I'm not an expert. And it much more easier to handle the result application side with limit (by hour for example) and not by range (greater than), even if the fetch in jdbc is awesome.

Comment: I later on figured out that range queries on `partition key`are allowed but they do not give correct result if the partitioner used is any other than `Order Preserving Partitioner (OPP)` .
However, **OPP is not recommended**  in cassandra now. More can be read here -> https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Partitioners. Still if someone wants the functionality of using range queries _(and can compromise with poor distribution of data across nodes)_, then you can change the  `partitioner` parameter to  `org.apache.cassandra.dht.OrderPreservingPartitioner`  in config file `cassandra.yaml`.

Answer (score 2):

In cassandra the primary key is also the partition key.
There is no point in creating a partition for each timeuuid ...
So usually you group things with the primary key and then use the clustering key to order.

Here's an example that is close to what I do :

```
create table sensors(
    location varchar, 
    timestamp timeuuid, 
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(location, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC) AND ...
```

Location is the partition key and timestamp the clustering key.

Then you can select like this :

```
SELECT * from sensors 
    where location='tarifa' 
    and timestamp > maxTimeuuid('2015-04-15 13:00') 
    and timestamp < minTimeuuid('2015-04-15 15:00');
```

Comment: Good answer.  One of the most common newbie mistakes in timeseries modeling (with Cassandra) is to try ordering the data by a single primary key.  Your solution is what I would have suggested, too.

Comment: Yeah, That's what everybody say to me, but the fact is : to make a delta, I have to query all the locations before ?? It's not really optimised :/

Comment: I am having the same problem, my partition key is `date_hour` . And upon running `select * from my_table where token(date_hour) < token('2014-02-03 12'); `    
It shows wrong results , i.e. entries whose `date_hour` is in 2015 too.  
Is it like we are not supposed to use range on partition key at all?

Comment: I am doing the same thing, but as soon as data size increases, fetching delta becomes slower linearly.